# Long text error with mysql

Tags: mysql, css

I'm having a bit of trouble with a submit form on my website. You enter your name, email, and content. The name and email submit just fine and content works whenever there are no special characters.

How do I allow for characters and spaces and such with that type of content on the database end? I have it at not null and long text.

Here is the css for the content area:

```
form textarea {
width: 45%;
height: 10em;
overflow-y: scroll;
resize: vertical;
}
```

Here is the html for the content area:

```
<div>Content:<br /><label></label><textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="s_content">`</textarea></div>`
```

Comment: can anyone help me? Am I using the wrong db syntax? Should I use blob?

Comment: My crystal ball is a bit dusty. Please provide more info and the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the column in MySQL as type TEXT rather than VARCHAR?

If you use the TEXT type you can store a lot more data.

Do send a bit more detail and perhaps some code which may help answer your issue.

Comment: He says he has it at ***"not null and long text"***